# Boot from something other than original hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, boot, bios, sata, dell-precision

I have a Dell Precision T7400 running Windows 7, BIOS version A02. Windows 7 is stored between 2 1TB SATA hard drives.

I recently obtained some SATA drives with another OS, but I cannot boot from them.

I unplugged the SATA cables from the old hard drives and plugged one into a new hard drive.

The BIOS sees the hard drive, but when I go to the boot menu, it tells me that there is no onboard SATA drive present.

I also have tried to boot from USB, but it will not do that either. It will only boot from the hard drives I got in it.

The USB drive has a working image because I am able to boot from it on a laptop and the hard drives were pulled out of working computers just days ago, then immediately handed to me.

How can I boot from my new drives?

Will I have to update the BIOS, or is there another problem?

It does not make sense that it would boot from one group of hard drives but not from a single hard drive.

Comment: The T7400 probably uses BIOS, which cannot see or boot from GPT disks, while the machines you pulled the drives from use UEFI which requires drives to be partitioned GPT for Windows to be able to boot. You will have to install Windows from scratch on the old machine, its disks are probably use the MBR partitioning scheme.

Comment: Expecting an OS of any kind to boot on different hardware than i t was installed on does not make sense either.